# How do I make using JS (no library) activate a CSS animation when a user scrolls to that section?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen several similar questions to this one, and the answers were mainly JS with a library (which I don't want...).

I would really appreciate if someone can send a JS code (if there is any...).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API will point you to the right direction - when the element enters the viewport, add the class that triggerst the css animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched this question more, and to my luck...

I found an answer!

(I am doing this for
those who want to know)

```html
<style>
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: #212933;
  color: #738BAA;
  font-family: 'Nunito';
}

section {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70% auto;
}
.content .left {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
.content .left p {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -25%;
  right: 17%;
  color: black;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 20vw;
  text-align: left;
}
.content .yellow {
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.content .squig {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 32%;
  left: 19%;
  width: 8vw;
}
.content .right {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
.content .right h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
}
.content .right p {
  line-height: 1.6em;
}

.anim {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2020-5-20 13:17:6
 * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
 * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */

/**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation slide-in-left
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
@-webkit-keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1000px);
            transform: translateX(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1000px);
            transform: translateX(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

</style>

</head>
<section>
    <h1 style="font-size: 50px; margin-left: 140px;">Scroll Down</h1>
</section>

<section class="content">
<div class="right">
<div class="anim" data-delay="0.2s" style="animation: 0s ease 0s 1 normal none running none;">
<h2>Hello I slide in when you see me!</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-157cd5b220a5c80d4ff8e0e70ac069bffd87a61252088146915e8726e5d9f147.js"></script>
<script id="rendered-js">
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.anim');

observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {

  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      entry.target.style.animation = `anim1 0.2s ${entry.target.dataset.delay} forwards ease-out`;
    } else
    {
      entry.target.style.animation = 'none';
    }
  });

});

images.forEach(image => {
  observer.observe(image);
});
//# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>
```

[I dumped the CSS and JavaScript in the HTML itself]

If the code snippit doesn't work, make it full page...